# How to copy prototype using reducer function of Array.reduce()

Tags: javascript, closures, javascript-objects

I have written a function to convert keys of a javascript object from lowercase to uppercase using combination of `Object.keys(obj)` and `Array.reduce()` -

```
function doCapitalizeFeatureKeys(in_obj){
    if(in_obj.features && in_obj.features.length > 0){
        const obj2 = in_obj.features.map(item =>
            Object.keys(item).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
                if(currentValue === "attributes" && item[currentValue]){
                    var cap = Object.keys(item[currentValue]).reduce((acc, curr) => {
                        acc[curr.toUpperCase()] = item[currentValue][curr];
                        return acc;
                    }, {});
                    accumulator[currentValue] = cap;
                } else {
                    accumulator[currentValue] = item[currentValue];
                }
                return accumulator; // line 14
            }, {}));
        in_obj.features = obj2;
        return in_obj;
    }
    return in_obj;
}
```

Below is the structure of the in_obj (for clarity) -

```
{
    "features": [
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "prnt_acct_id": "034037",
                    "chld_acct_id": "030614"
                },
                "geometry":"",
                "symbol":"",
                [[Prototype]]
            },
            {
                "attributes": {
                    "prnt_acct_id": "034038",
                    "chld_acct_id": "030615"
                },
                "geometry":"",
                "symbol":"",
                [[Prototype]]
            }
        ]
}
```

The problem is that the accumulator in reducer function is not inheriting prototype of feature object. I have tried `Object.setPrototypeOf(accumulator,item)` at line 14 but that inherits lowercase attributes along with the prototype so the resulting obj has both lowercase and uppercase attributes, I only want to keep uppercase attributes. I am looking for a neater way of inheriting the prototype of `item` into `accumulator` without existing lowercase attributes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does the custom prototype come from in the first place? If this is not a plain object, please show us how you are constructing it.

Comment: You should not be using `Object.keys(item).reduce(…)` anyway if you only want to change `item.attributes` specifically

Comment: You should not set the prototype to `item`, you should set it to `item`'s prototype. And you should not set it in line 14 (inside the loop over the properties), you should just create the object with the correct prototype from the beginning. Use `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(item))` instead of `{}` as the initial value for the accumulator.

Comment: custom prototype is coming from Feature class of `arcgis` javascript library

Comment: Then probably you should rather construct a `new Feature(…)` in that `map(…)` callback instead of somehow attempting to clone the object yourself